# Koin DI crashes with release signed apk

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, release, koin

I have an application that uses Koin DI framework. I have set all the modules for Retrofit, Database, Repository etc and works fine in the debug mode. Lately i uploaded it on Play Store but i see that it crashes when i try to launch the app. The problem is that it cannot create an Instance for my Repository class which of course has its dependencies.
Here is the error that i get on my Logcat

```
2020-09-09 17:23:37.690 19662-19662/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.myapp, PID: 19662
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsListActivity}: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'com.mypackage.repositories.server.ServerRepository']
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3632)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'com.mypackage.repositories.server.ServerRepository']
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:59)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KoinComponent.kt:67)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel.getServerRepository(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel.getServerAccounts(AccountsViewModel.kt:37)
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsListActivity.onCreate(AccountsListActivity.kt:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'com.mypackage.managers.api.ApiManager']
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:59)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$repositoryModule$1$1.invoke(Modules.kt:208)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$repositoryModule$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40) 
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48) 
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87) 
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214) 
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181) 
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KoinComponent.kt:67) 
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81) 
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel.getServerRepository(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsViewModel.getServerAccounts(AccountsViewModel.kt:37) 
        at com.mypackage.ui.activities.accounts.accountlist.AccountsListActivity.onCreate(AccountsListActivity.kt:97) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder']
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:59)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
2020-09-09 17:23:37.691 19662-19662/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$managersModule$1$3.invoke(Modules.kt:204)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$managersModule$1$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
            ... 33 more
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'okhttp3.OkHttpClient']
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:59)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$7.invoke(Modules.kt:204)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$7.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
            ... 41 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Single instance created couldn't return value
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:50)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$6.invoke(Modules.kt:200)
        at com.mypackage.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$6.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
            ... 49 more
```

My build.gradle is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
   
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }

        resConfigs "en"

       
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        myapp {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".myapp"
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0'

    // Firebase && Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'

    // Lifecycle (ViewModel & LiveData)
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // Gson to Kotlin Object
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // Coroutines for Kotlin
    def coroutines_version = "1.3.5"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    // Room Database
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Koin DI
    def koin_version = "2.1.6"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"

    // Navigation Components
    def nav_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Butterknife
    def butterknifeVersion = '10.2.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3"

    // Preferences
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"

    // Work Manager (Kotlin + coroutines)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"

    // Paging
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.2'

    // Circle Image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    // Gallery picker
    implementation 'com.kroegerama:bottomsheet-imagepicker:1.1.2'

    // Sliding up Panel
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'

    // Material Search bar
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'

    // Material About page
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:0.2.3'

    // Material Spinner
    implementation 'com.github.chivorns.androidx:smartmaterialspinner:1.2.1'

    // Pin Lock View
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'

    // Image editor
    implementation 'com.github.iamutkarshtiwari:Ananas:1.2.4'

    // Volley SyncRequests
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    // Retrofit Requests
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.9.0'

    // Retrofit logging interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'

    // Glide for ImageLoading
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Video Compress
    implementation "com.github.AbedElazizShe:LightCompressor:0.7.0"

    // Qr Code scanner
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Twilio
    implementation "com.twilio:video-android:5.6.0"
    implementation "com.twilio:audioswitch:0.1.0"
    implementation "com.twilio:twilio-android-env:1.0.0"

    // OpenCv for Grayscale video
    // implementation "com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:3.4.1"

    // -----DEBUG MODE--- //

    // Database monitor --for Emulator we run "adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080"
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'

    // Logback
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0'

}
```

The modules declaration for the Koin is the following

```
import androidx.room.Room
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.dsl.module
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

val networkModule = module {
    single<Gson> {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        return@single gsonBuilder.setLenient().create()
    }

    single<Interceptor?> {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) return@single null

        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return@single httpLoggingInterceptor
    }

    single {
        return@single HeaderInterceptor()
    }

    single {
        return@single NetworkResponseAdapterFactory()
    }

    single {
        return@single BaseUrlHolder(BuildConfig.BASE_HOLDER_URL)
    }

    single<OkHttpClient> {
        val loggingInterceptor = get<Interceptor?>()
        val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            addInterceptor(get<HeaderInterceptor>())
            loggingInterceptor?.let {
                addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            }
        }
        return@single httpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    single<Retrofit.Builder> {
        return@single Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .client(get<OkHttpClient>())
    }

    single<MyAppApiService> {
        return@single get<Retrofit>().create(MyAppApiService::class.java)
    }
}

val databaseModule = module {

    single {
        return@single BuildConfig.DATABASE_NAME
    }

    single {
        return@single Room
            .databaseBuilder(androidContext(), AppDatabase::class.java, get())
            .build()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().serverDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().accountsDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().siteDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().accountGroupsDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().siteRolesDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().formsDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().messageDao()
    }

    single {
        get<AppDatabase>().messageQueueDao()
    }
}

val repositoryModule = module {
    single<ServerRepository> {
        return@single ServerRepositoryImpl(get(), get(), get())
    }

    single<AccountsRepository> {
        return@single AccountsRepositoryImpl(
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            get(),
            androidContext(),
            get()
        )
    }

    single<FormsRepository> {
        return@single FormsRepositoryImpl(get())
    }

    single<MessagesRepository> {
        return@single MessagesRepositoryImpl(get(), get(), get(), get(), get(), get(), androidContext())
    }

    single<FriendShipRepository> {
        return@single FriendShipRepositoryImpl(get(), get(), get())
    }
}

val managersModule = module {
    single<SharedPrefsData<Settings>> {
        return@single SharedPrefsDataImpl<Settings>(androidContext(), Settings.prefsName)
    }

    single<SharedPrefsManager> {
        return@single SharedPrefsManagerImpl(androidContext(), get())
    }

    single<ApiManager> {
        return@single ApiManagerImpl(get(), get())
    }

    single<RoomManager> {
        return@single RoomManagerImpl(androidContext(), get(), get())
    }
}

val lifecycleModule = module {
    single {
        return@single MyAppLifeCycleObserver()
    }
}
```

Why is this happening since the Koin is set up correclty (because it works in debug mode)???

Comment: Can you post your code? I'd also suggest posting your gradle files as well.

Comment: I have edited the post with the Modules file and the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved.
It seems that the provider for httpLoggingInterceptor that return NULL if it is debug mode could not create the single. So i changed my code to

```
single<Interceptor> {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return@single httpLoggingInterceptor
    }

.....

single {
        val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            addInterceptor(get<HeaderInterceptor>())
            if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) addInterceptor(get<Interceptor>())
        }

        return@single httpClientBuilder.build()
    }
```

Now it works.